# onbeforeunload any way to know if it is reload or leave?

Tags: javascript

We have some forms that users fill out. If during the process the navigate away I need to perform an action.

I've found many examples of combining `onbeforeunload` and `unload` in the browser to prompt the user the user and remind them that if they close or navigate away the information they have entered won't be saved. That part is working well.

The only problem I still have is if the user reloads -- right-click reload, F5, or browser refresh button -- then the `unload` is also called. This is a problem for us.

I found information about the [performance.navigation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/navigation) property. But the values of that aren't available until after the page reloads, that is, it tells me that the page I'm on has been reloaded, but not that the page is about to be reloaded.

Is there any way to detect an impending refresh as opposed to a navigate away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

I recommend you "perform an action" as your user is filling out the form. Then if the user chooses to leave, no harm done.

It's perfectly feasible to post this information to a server as it is being populated. If the "perform an action" requires interaction with the user, you should just do that interaction on `beforeunload`.

**EDIT:** At the point of `beforeunload`, the only interaction that can be provided is an alert() asking the user to OK / Cancel navigating away from the page.

Comment: Darn. Not the answer I was hoping for, but good to know none the less.